# Magento 1.9 - How to apply handling fees if selected products available along with other products in the cart?

Tags: cart, addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento1.9.2.3, extrafee

If the cart contains any one of the selected products along with other products that should be applied handling fees and cart contains only the selected products no need to apply handling fees.

Here I am using [Extra fees module](https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee)

Using the shopping cart price rule,

[image]

Here how to add a condition like if a customer tries to add other products to the cart but cart have already selected products then should be applied to handling fees.

Now, if more than one special products (all special listed in https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRGD9.png ) exist in cart handling charge applied, i need this for other products.

How to do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add another if condition from the second plus:

if an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true:

```
- SKU is not one of [selected products]
- Quantity in cart is greater than one
```